# Traffic routing not working between IP and interface

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, iptables

The debian server is configured like this:

```
enp0s8 = WAN
enp0s10 = LAN (Internet via tun0)
enp0s12 = LAN access only, no internet available
tun0 = Main VPN Connection
tun1 = Secondary VPN Connection
```

I'm trying to forward the traffic originating from 192.7.0.6 to the secondary VPN Connection, while all other devices gets internet via tun0.

My iptables configuration currently is:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s10 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o enp0s10 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

First I tried using this to enable forwarding to the secondary VPN interface and route 192.7.0.6 to it:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s10 -o tun1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun1 -o enp0s10 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
ip route add 192.7.0.6 dev tun1
```

Doing this just blocked internet for 192.7.0.6. I also tried using PREROUTING and POSTROUTING (DNAT and SNAT) but that makes the same effect as:

```
ip route add 192.7.0.6 dev tun1
```

Is there any way I can make it work?